# linqpad Invalid high surrogate character

Tags: linqpad

> Invalid high surrogate character (0xDEF9). A high surrogate character must have a value from range (0xD800 - 0xDBFF).

Every query in LinqPad gives me this message, I am running the premium version and this has just started happening recently, any ideas what it means and how to diagnose where the issue is?

here's the stack:

```
at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.EncodeSurrogate(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd, Char* pDst)
at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(String text)
at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteElement(XElement e)
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.GetXmlString(SaveOptions o)
at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ToString()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<GroupJoinIterator>d__6a`4.MoveNext()
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement..ctor(XName name, Object[] content)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement..ctor(XName name, Object[] content)
```

Comment: Maybe you should also try the official forum: http://forum.linqpad.net/

Comment: Thanks Stephan but i went there first and cannot for the life of me see how to add a new question, therefore i have come here instead. Plus there's not a lot of activity on it.

Comment: Well... that's true...

Comment: Have you customized the style sheet? (Edit | Preferences | Results, style sheet...)

Comment: Hi joe, nope, i imagine it is something to do with db types but it's a tough one to get down to.